# Why ignore_sticky_posts argument is in sticky post query?

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, sticky-post

We all know that `ignore_sticky_posts` is used to exclude sticky post from your custom query.

But why on [WordPress Theme Development documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/), they use `ignore_sticky_posts` in querying sticky posts?

```php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This is so confusing and doesn't make any sense! You want it and yet you exclude it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> We all know that `ignore_sticky_posts` is used to exclude sticky post from your custom query.

#### - No, this assumption is wrong.

---

### What `ignore_sticky_posts` means:

Even though in natural English, `ignore_sticky_posts` sounds like WordPress should ignore all sticky posts from the query, in reality that is not what WordPress does. Instead, you should read `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` argument as follows:

> When `ignore_sticky_posts` is set to `true` or `1`, WordPress will **ignore the procedure** of setting the sticky posts within your custom query.

---

### What WordPress does when `ignore_sticky_posts` is not set:

To clearly understand what `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` does, you need to understand what WordPress does when `ignore_sticky_posts` argument is not set or it's set to `false` or `0` (by default):

1. If there are posts within the query result that are part of stick posts, WordPress will push them to the top of the query result.
2. If any sticky post is not present within the query result, WordPress will get all those sticky posts from the database again and set them to the top of the query result.

So when the argument is set as `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`, WordPress simply **ignores the above procedure**, that's all. It doesn't exclude them specifically. For that you need to set `post__not_in` argument.

---

### Explanation of the codex example:

Now, let's come to the example from the codex:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Here codex is only setting `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` **to be efficient, nothing more**. Even without having it, you will get the same expected result:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, in this case, since `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` argument is not set, WordPress will needlessly do all those procedure of setting sticky posts to the top of the results, even though all of these results (from this example) are only sticky posts.

---

Best way to learn something in WordPress is to examine the core CODE. So for even clearer understanding, examine [this part of WordPress CODE](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.7-branch/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2941-L2980).

Comment: WordPress should include your answer on their sticky post page!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. WordPress codex is editable, even you can edit it and add this answer as reference for others ;)

Comment: This answer is very much underrated. I've actually come back to it twice now, a year apart. That's how confusing this parameter is.

Comment: Brilliant answer fayaz.  Detailed and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that would be easier in my opinion though some of the thoughts already mentioned are pretty good.

```
    $args=array(
        'post__not_in'=>get_option('sticky_posts')
        // add in any other arguments you want here
    );
    $posts=new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Be careful when you do this though. This list can get really long, in theory, resulting a query that is very heavy on the database potentially. What your query does is not the actual intended function of sticky posts, as properly explained in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/260951/1763

Comment: The goal is to not include any sticky posts at all, not just ignore the way the sticky idea works but to simply not show any.