# What's difference between "ignore_sticky_posts" and "post__not_in"=>$sticky_posts

Tags: sticky-post

what's the difference in results from:

```
new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
```

and

```
new WP_Query( array( 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
```

?

Comment: Have a look here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260941/why-ignore-sticky-posts-in-sticky-post-query

Comment: @PiyushRawat thanks, i've clarified that. post that as answer, and I will upvote it.

Comment: No issues, credit goes to the other guy for such a clarified example..:)